# Browser will not display appended text after clicking links in php

Tags: php

The following code should display "Cow selected" when I click the link "Cow" or "Dog selected" when I click "Dog". Since I'm using GET instead of POST, the "id" will display "?id%20=%20#" depending on which link I click for the switch statement in the address bar. However, it seems like the switch statement is ignored and doesn't even run.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>                                                          
<html lang="en">                                                         
        <head>                                                           
                <meta charset="UTF-8">                                    
                <title>Appending link data</title>                       
        </head>                                                          
        <body>                                                           
                <?php                                                    
                        if(isset($_GET['id']))                           
                        {                                                
                                $id = $_GET['id'];                       

                                switch($id)                              
                                {                                        
                                        case 1:                          
                                                echo 'Cow selected<hr>'; 
                                                break;                   
                                        case 2:                          
                                                echo 'Dog selected<hr>'; 
                                                break;                   
                                        case 3:                          
                                                echo 'Goat selected<hr>';
                                                break;                   
                                }                                        
                        }                                                

                        echo '<h1>Select a buddy</h1>';                  
                        echo '<p><a href="link.php?id = 1">Cow</a> | ';  
                        echo '<a href="link.php?id = 2">Dog</a> | ';     
                        echo '<a href="link.php?id = 3">Goat</a></p>';   
                ?>                                                       
        </body>                                                          
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting spaces in the URLs, hence the `%20` values (URL encoded space). Drop the spaces and the code should run fine.

E.g. `echo '<p><a href="link.php?id=1">Cow</a> | ';`